# How do I find in-link history of an object in DOORS?

Tags: ibm-doors

## Background

In DOORS, each object can have both out-links (red arrows pointing right) and in-links (yellow arrows pointing left). You can find the history of out-links with the following procedure:

1. Right click on an object.
2. Select **Properties...** from the drop down menu.
3. Click on the **History** tab.
4. Any item that says **Modify Object: Create out-link** or **Modify Object: Delete out-link** has to do with the modification of out-links on an object.

However, no where can I find the history of in-links unless I happen to remember the past module that used to link into the selected object. This has lead me to ask...

## Question

Where can I find the history of **in**-links of an object in DOORS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Links are always stored in the outgoing module, not in the incoming module (you can notice e.g. that you don't need to open the target module in an edit mode to create an in link, but you always need to open the source module in an edit mode).

Long story short: You find the history of in-links indirectly by looking at the out-links in the other modules.

Comment: about the question how to find out which objects may have linked into the current module in the past: you can get a hint by reading the link modules in your project. There should be a link set in one of the link modules with the current module as target.